# How do I manipulate an external list view's columns with javascript?

Tags: list-view, external-list

I want to manipulate the columns of an external list view (XsltListViewWebPart), however, as the data loads asynchronously I must wait for the data to load and the table to be generated before my code can run.

I assume I need to use a callback but can't find anything.

Comment: Is this 2010 or 2013? For 2013, using JSLink could be an awesome option for you

Comment: 2010. I ended up just polling for the existence of the table with class ms-listviewtable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just polling for the existence of the table containing the data, which will have class `ms-listviewtable`. (I'm using jQuery here.)

```
$(function(){
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('.ms-listviewtable').length > 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            // Code here
        }
    }, 100);
});
```